# Git rebase to remove extra initial commit

Tags: git, github, rebase

I've been trying to remove 2 extra commits at the start of my repo - but when i think I am successful, I push to an empty repo on github and the network graph shows no change.

How it happened is: My friend pushed an initial commit - with a 10 meg library. I told him we would start over so I didn't pull and I made a new initial commit and force pushed. I told him to delete his git folder, but he only deleted all the files in the folder, excluding the .git folder. When he pulled, he made a merge commit, and I didn't notice for a while.

Now the beginning of our git history looks like this:

[image]

The blue bit was my second initial commit. When he merged, he simply overwrote everything with my commit. At this point, I have tried going back to my initial commit in a new branch and rebasing and ensuring that I don't "pick" his initial commit, but when I push to an empty repo, his extra initial commit shows up again. I have also tried going back to my initial commit labeled 2 and hand picking (cherry-picking) every commit starting from the one labeled 4 (skipping the other initial commit 1 and merge commit 3). Neither of this is working as both 1 and 3 still get pushed to an empty repo after rebase finished. Is there no way to remove 1 and 3? Since 3 simply throws away all of 1, I think it should be able to.

The rebase commands I used were

`git checkout -b tmpfix`

`git rebase --root -i`

and

`git branch -b tmpfix <sha1>`

`git cherry-pick <sha1>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution. Tedious, but worth it for the 98% size reduction in the repo. I'll try to make this as clear as possible - AFAIK this only works with rewriting the whole git history from the initial commit.

[image: Messed up git history]

- Let's say the main repo is in ~/repo
- Create a new repo in ~/newRepo (`mkdir ~/newRepo`, `cd ~/newRepo`, `git init`)
- Add the remote of the main repo to newRepo (`git remote add original git@github.com:...`)
- Find the commit you want to start at. Since my initial commit was incorrect, I started with the commit I wanted to be my initial commit (Labeled 2 in my image, I think you may have to start with your intended initial commit. If your intended initial commit has a history, you may have to squash it.)
- Fetch the original remote into your new repo (`git fetch original`)
- Start cherry picking, starting with initial commit (`git cherry-pick xxxxxxx` for a single commit or `git cherry-pick xxxxxxx^..xxxxxxx` for a range, inclusive)
- Once you finish your master branch, move on to any branches that came from master
- Find the commit where the other branch branched off (the last shared commit between the other branch and master), the hash will be different in the newRepo after it got cherry picked, so double check it or you will pull in the whole old history on accident
- Jump to that commit using `git checkout xxxxxxx`
- When you jump, git should give you a command (`git checkout -b branch-name`) to save a new branch. Make sure that exactly matches the branch you are on.
- Now start cherry picking again, starting with the first unique commit to that branch

Once you finish master and all connected branches, a force push should rewrite history.

I haven't found a way to preserve history where it branches and merges - it ended up being one continuous line for me, but any branches that aren't merged will still show up as such.